# Why doesn't my pen ballpoint or nib emerge?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

https://i.imgur.com/SfdRluq.mp4. This shows a working pen. How can I make the GIF show up?

When I rotate that silver part on the broken pen, the [nib](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/test-cases-for-pen/) doesn't emerge.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Either it is not assembled correctly or the refill is incorrect.

Edit based on comment: refills are usually available in several sizes (of diameter and length), so using the wrong one may mean the nib will no longer protrude sufficiently”.

Also, if the parts are not assembled correctly then the nib can fail to protrude and while some have few parts which makes this unlikely with other models it can happen - based on personal experience of dis- and re- assembling pens.

Comment: can you elaborate pls???

Comment: @Filippetto elaborate? Like expanding “refill is incorrect” to “ refills are usually available in several sizes (of diameter and length), so using the wrong one may mean the nib will no longer protrude sufficiently”

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the push bottom, there is a stepped gear mating with the end of refill'

every push turns the gear one step up and down.

Many times cleaning and re-engaging those two gears does the job.

Comment: "At the end of the push bottom" My pen doesn't have push button. Did you see my GIF and pics? I removed the diagram because I think it's confusing you.